# Prevent abusive submissions within time period

Tags: php, symfony, session, cookies, throttling

I have a php 5.5 web app using the Symfony2 framework and would like to keep the server load at a minimum.  A few pages on my site allows the user to retrieve a list of objects from a database and one set has several hundred thousand rows, and will be over a million soon.  Unregistered users are able to use this page.

I want to prevent the user from performing a query too many times in a minute or some similar timespan and have seen this implemented on other websites, including stackoverflow for comments or voting.

How is this implemented?  Do I need to create a cookie and check the session on each page load to see if the specific actions I want to limit have been used and prevent the form submission?  Is there a standard way of handling this in php, or specifically for Symfony2?  I have searched for this and found some similar questions, but no specific answer.  This is for users directly on my site and not using an api.

[How to throttle API requests using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809829/how-to-throttle-api-requests-using-php)

[How do I throttle my site's API users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375501/how-do-i-throttle-my-sites-api-users)

## Edit:

I know cookies are not the proper way to go and will try to implement a mechanism using a cache.  I'm using php 5.5 and read that APC has some bugs with 5.5, therefore Zend OpCache is actually preferred along with APCu.  Can anyone show an example of using Zend OpCache / APCu to log and track user requests?

Comment: Cookies reside on the client side. All I need to do is disable them and I can spam you all I want (and many bots don't handle cookies anyways)

Comment: Yes, I was worried about that and need a more robust solution

Comment: could you approve the answer if it's good?

Comment: thanks for the expanded answer.  I will mark it as correct but still wait another day in case anyone else will respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies is not the secure way. When I did something of similar, I used APC or MongoDB to store the counter, with a key made with:

- IP: $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] | $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
- Browser: $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
- absolute timestamp of this hour (or minutes if you want to check shortly)

So for example you can store an APC key named with: ip2long($ip), crc32($browser), time() - time() % 3600, and save there your hit value.

I put an example of code that made use only of the IP in a range of 1 hour.

```
// Time
$now = time();
$time = $now - $now%3600;

// IP
if(array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', $_SERVER)) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
$key = sprintf('%d-%u', $time, ip2long($ip));

if (apc_inc($key)) {
    echo "we have ". apc_fetch($key). " views in this hour";
}
```

Comment: I'm using postgresql and would use like to use APC.  The is a very small amount of memory, but what size of user base would make it so large that I should shift this to the database?  Should I manually clear this or let the cache manage itself?

Comment: It depends on how long you want maintain your log, if is only one minute you don't need to have this persistent

Comment: Do you know if these same functions work using APCu?  There are very few documents on APCu that I can find.